# Reading data from a csv file and storing into an array, my file opens correctly however the file is being read incorrectly

Tags: java, csv

```
    String fileName = "MSFT.csv";
    File file = new File(fileName);
    try{
        Scanner inputStream = new Scanner(file);
        while(inputStream.hasNext()){
            String data = inputStream.next();
            System.out.println(data);
        }
        inputStream.close();
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
```

I am attempting to read from a csv file and when I run this code to make sure the file is being read correctly all of the comma separated data displays correctly with the exception of the first line. The first line from the file is being output with each word being on a different line. What am I doing wrong with my initial reading of the file?

An example of my output goes as:
Timestamp,
close,
high,
low,
open,
value,
9:30,57.515,57.57,57.47,57.515,31120
Now all of my words in this case are on the same line in the excel file, but when I run it timestamp, close, high, etc all appear on different lines so I'm not sure why it appears like this.

Comment: There are CSV reader libraries. In this case do `hasNextLine()` first.

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean by this, replace my hasNext() with hasNextLine()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Scanner hasNext is defined as follows:

> hasNext() Returns true if this scanner has another token in its input.

So when you use it your are reading your csv file token by token and not line by line. Beside that using the Scanner next does the following:

> next() Finds and returns the next complete token from this scanner.

And finally using `System.out.println` will insert a line separator after printing your data, which is why it keeps going to the next line after outputing each token.

Change your code as follows and it should work as expected:

```
String fileName = "MSFT.csv";
File file = new File(fileName);
try{
   Scanner inputStream = new Scanner(file);
   while(inputStream.hasNextLine()){
      String data = inputStream.nextLine();
      System.out.println(data);
   }
   inputStream.close();
}  catch(FileNotFoundException e){
   e.printStackTrace();
```